# Delete column(s) that do not contain specific value - DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Looking for assistance in deleting columns that do not contain a specific value. For this example, columns should be deleted if they do not contain the value 1 (i.e. Col1 and Col3 should remain)

```
ex1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
ex2 = [5,6,7,8,9]
ex3 = [10,1,2,3,4]
ex4 = [2,3,4,5,6]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':ex1, 'Col2':ex2, 'Col3':ex3, 'Col4':ex4})

for col in df1.columns:
   if 'CONDITION HERE' in col:
      del df1[col]
```

Unsure of how to deal with the condition. Perhaps `value_counts() < 1` of a specific number?

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: Use `df1.loc[:, df1.eq(1).any()]`

Comment: It works! Thanks!